# Angular2 datetime picker suggestions

Tags: angular, datetime, datetimepicker, angular2-forms

I am looking for a datetime picker in Angular2,- I have a datetimepicker using HTML5 by setting input type as date and this works.
It however doesn't meet my requirements as I need to set the mindate based on today's date minus 5 days and maxdate is today - runtime validation. So can't really hard-code values in html.

Tried to use **ngbDatepicker** but it didn't work.

Any suggestions really appreciated.

Below is my code whilst trying to use ngbDatePicker:-

App.module.shared.ts

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
declarations:
[
    AppComponent
],
imports:
[
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
]
```

DateComponent.ts

```
export class DateComponent implements OnInit
{
      public model : Date;
}
```

DateComponent.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" name="dp" 
  [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [ngModelOptions]="
  {standalone: true}">
 <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" >
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </div>

</div>
```

Clicking on the calendar doesn't display the datetimepicker

Comment: What "didn't work" in `ngbDatepicker`, exactly?

Comment: Please provide the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly subjective question, so you are likely to get opinion based responses - including this one.

That said, you dont *need* to use a 3rd party component for this - although you certainly could - but a quick google will reveal these, so I wont mention them.

Avoiding 3rd party options, if you're using Model Driven Forms you could do this very easily yourself with a combination of HTML5 `input type='date'` (as you had before) and a custom angular validator. Something like the following:

*HTML*

```
<form [formGroup]="validateExampleForm">
  <label>some date to be validated:</label>
  <input type="date" formControlName="someDate"><br> Valid: {{validateExampleForm && validateExampleForm.controls.someDate.valid}}<br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

*Typescript*

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.validateExampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        someDate: [this.dateValue, (control) => this.validateIsDateInLastFiveDays(control)]
    });
}

validateIsDateInLastFiveDays(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } {
    let val = control.value;
    let minDateValue: Date = new Date();
    minDateValue.setDate(minDateValue.getDate() - 5);

    if (!dates.inRange(new Date(val), minDateValue, this.today)) {
        return { "someerrortype": true };
    }

    return null;
}
```

Full plunker here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/XT4YzCYPdD6lpBGlzpII?p=preview

**NB** `dates` object used for date range check code is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497790

Comment: Thanks @Steveland83